# Entity Framework setting Identity Value with composite key Azure SQL

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

We've recently switched our existing product to using Entity Framework Code First Migrations. The transition has been rather painful, but we've gotten through almost all of it at this point. Now that we've got things working in our local environments we've pushed it out to our deployment environment. Unfortunately our deployment environment doesn't appear to support **SOMETHING** with the new EF Migrations.

Our environment consists of two servers: a Web (.Net MVC3) server and a socket server, both running in Windows Azure. The problem only seems to occur in our socket server, and in fact Entity Framework is telling us that the database hash doesn't match (using `context.Database.CompatibleWithModel()`).

If we ignore the fact that EF is telling us that our DB Model doesn't match our code model, the only error we encounter is the insertion of an entity object with a **composite key**. All other entities can be created fine. All of our entity classes derive from a base class:

```
class BaseEntity {
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
}
```

We had to add the 'Order' piece in order for EF to support the composite keys. The model that is having issues looks like:

```
class SubEntity {
    [MaxLength(255)]
    [Required]
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When we attempt to add a new `SubEntity` object to the context and save the changes, we get an error from SQL saying that we cannot set an explicit `Id`, and to use `IDENTITY_INSERT ON`.

**The code works fine on our local machines, and in our web server. The DB model is compatible, and we can create 'SubEntity' objects without issue.**

To me, it seems like EF, in the socket server environment, is ignoring the `[DatabaseGenerated]` Annotation when using a composite key. That would explain the error, and explain why the DB model is not compatible. Does this make sense? Is there something in the environment that would make EF behave differently?

Answer (score 1):

After 4 days of beating my head against my { desk, wall, co-workers fist }, I FINALLY found the solution to the problem (even though I don't understand it).

Again, this only happens when we run the server in a Windows Azure environment (doesn't happen on our local environments), and apparently it only happens when running in our socket server (Photon by ExitGames).

For some reason, the annotation `[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]`, which is an MVC annotation (and therefore shouldn't affect our Photon server) is causing EntityFramework to say that the `Id` property doesn't exist for the `SubEntity` class.

Removing the `HiddenInput` attribute fixes the problem. So, although it is 'fixed', I still don't understand why.